# Localization of database kept in asset folder?

Tags: android, localization, android-emulator, android-sqlite

I have a issue.I have developed my database using sqlite database browser.i kept it in asset folder and i am accessing that database .everthing is okk,but the issue is i want localization.I want those data coming from db in marathi ,gujrati ,english based on the locale setting of emulator/handset...

any soln pls

Answer (score 0):

Add locale to the primary key of your table.

Comment: will u pls elaborate me why this to be done to resolve this issue